# Image load fail after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, zend-framework

I'm new here and i got a question that i don't find the answer...

I got an web app running on Zend with MVC. On client side, Using Jquery I perform an Ajax call that return some data in a Json format. With an javascript methode i'm able to create the HTML code corresponding to the result. Until here that's fine all is working well :-)

My problem is when I try to generate an html component such as Image where an URL is needed.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON("/index/items", function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items.push('<li id="resultList-' + val.id + '" class="resultList"><img src="images/item.jpg" alt="img">' + val.name + '</li>');
        });

        $('<ul/>', {
            'id': 'resultList',
            'class': 'myClass',
            html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('#divResult');
    });
</script>

<div id="content">
    <div id="divResult"></div>
</div>
```

So i put in the image `src="images/item.jpg`

My problem is that the image is not found, I only get the 'alt' label -> Error 404.

When I open firebug, i can see a GET query on the URL:

> http ://myWebsite/controller/images/item.jpg

For sure, the server could not find it here because I put the image in a:
`/project/public/images` folder...

According to you:

1. Do you think implementation is good (safe) ?
2. What is the best way to fix my problem ?

Please understand that all this is new for me and I try to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to put it in a relative path.

Example if the directory structure is:

```
project/
   html/
     htmlfile.html //references the image file
   js/
     jsfile.js //references the image file
   images/
     item.png
```

Then you need to use

```
<img src="../images/item.jpg" alt="img" />
```

This specifies the path to the image file relative to the file that is accessing the image.

Comment: And I didn't think about that... sorry.

Comment: *"relative to the js file"* -> *relative to the .html file* where the javascript is executing.